# Simulate Click with Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a SELECT element that I am replacing with a dropdown. I have successfully created the dropdown from the SELECT and child OPTION elements, but I need to add a click event.

This click event would be as such:

If LI is clicked, also click corresponding OPTION.

This is because Woocommerce must have some JS or PHP working where depending on the option, it shows stock status and variable amount. As such, I assume that the click event will also bind the OPTION value to the form for adding to cart.

I have this JS code:

```
window.onload = main;
function main(){ 
var select = document.querySelector('.turnintodropdown');
var selsOpts = document.querySelector('.turnintodropdown option');
var selsLi = document.querySelector('.selectOption');
var trigger = document.createElement('a');
var openDropdown = 'dropdownVisible';
var closeDropdown = 'dropdownHidden';

(function addDropdown() {
    if(select) {
        var selsCon = document.createElement('div');
        var selsOuter = document.createElement('ul');
        selsCon.classList.add('selectContainer');
        selsOuter.classList.add('selectOuter');
        select.parentNode.insertBefore(selsCon, select);
        selsCon.appendChild(selsOuter);
        for(var i=0; i<select.length; i++) {
            if(select.childNodes[i].classList.contains('enabled') || select.childNodes[i].innerHTML == '- -'){ // Select First Child and <option> Tags with Enabled Class

                // Create New Elements
                var optsNew = document.createElement('li');
                optsNew.innerHTML = select.childNodes[i].text;
                optsNew.classList.add('selectOption');

                // Set Attributes to New Elements
                if(optsNew.innerHTML !== '- -') {
                    optsNew.setAttribute('value', select.childNodes[i].text);
                }
                else {
                    void(0);
                }

                optsNew.click(clickFunc);

                // Add New LI <option> to UL <container>
                selsOuter.appendChild(optsNew);

                // Click Events
                console.log(select.firstChild);
            }
        }
        var clickFunc = function() {
            select.click();
        };
        select.style.display = 'none';

    }

})();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Michael

Comment: WordPress has jQuery. WooCommerce uses it. So why not jQuery? That would make it easier, for a start.

Comment: Get the index of the clicked `<li>` and use this to set the `selectedIndex` property of the `<select>`

Comment: Oh I'm sure it would make it heaps easier. But seeing as though I'm currently learning JavaScript, I would rather know vanilla JS a lot more thoroughly before writing in other frameworks.

Comment: Hi @Andreas I should have mentioned that I have tried this and it seems to only show the `option` rather than "click" it.

Comment: @user3436334 it's a hard way to learn the browser support problems and such, you'll come to these kind of frameworks one day for this very reason i bet. Considering that, how far do you want to go in term of older browsers support? the answer will vary a little depending on that

Comment: Hi @Kaddath, in terms of browser support, I am looking at browsers that support ES2015 - so nothing ancient like IE8 or IE9. Like my CSS - anything with about 90% or above support.

Comment: Where's `<li>` located in the HTML hierarchy? Can you show us the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit long to answer, sorry.

the function was originally taken from [this webpage](http://www.nonobtrusive.com/2011/11/29/programatically-fire-crossbrowser-click-event-with-javascript/) and not modified, it is supposed to work with most old browsers. I actually tested on last versions of Firefox / Chrome / Opera / Edge with success.

The version which handles all types of events is more complicated because you have to make cases for standard events to process them by type (not all are `MouseEvents`).

It also supports the inline functions, with `onclick=` in the html tag, and works also for events set with jQuery.

Note that if you want the same support for old broswers, you'll have to differentiate cases for the setting of events too, the modern `addEventListener` being not supported by all.

```
function fireClick(node){
    if ( document.createEvent ) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initEvent('click', true, false);
        node.dispatchEvent(evt);    
    } else if( document.createEventObject ) {
        node.fireEvent('onclick') ; 
    } else if (typeof node.onclick == 'function' ) {
        node.onclick(); 
    }
}
```

used like this for example:

```
fireClick(document.getElementById("myId"));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Vanilla JS (without jQuery)

```
/**
 * Simulate a click event.
 * @public
 * @param {Element} elem  the element to simulate a click on
 */
var simulateClick = function (elem) {
    // Create our event (with options)
    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window
    });
    // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
    var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

To use it, call the function, passing in the element you want to simulate the click on.

```
var someLink = document.querySelector('a');
simulateClick(someLink);
```

src / full article: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-simulate-a-click-event-with-javascript/